# How do I enable passwordless sudo for all options for a command?

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, apt

I'd like to enable passwordless sudo for `sudo apt update`, and also have passwordless sudo work for the `apt update` command when I run it with options like `sudo apt update -q` and `sudo apt update -qq`.

I have the file `/etc/sudoers.d/apt` with these contents:

```
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update
```

This gives me passwordless sudo for `sudo apt update`, but passwordless sudo fails when I call the command with an option such as `sudo apt update -q`.

I know I can account for options by listing out each one in `/etc/sudoers.d/apt`, but I'd prefer something which will work for all available options without me needing to foresee which ones I might want to use in the future.

Comment: Also, consider creating a group (or using the system provided group for that purpose, (either `wheel` or `sudo` groups), to ensure you limit the capability to only members of that group.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I thought that the `%sudo` at the beginning was limiting it to users in the `sudo` group, which it sounds to me is what you're suggesting. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yep -- sorry looked right past that. Still used to the traditional `wheel` group `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most robust way that I can see to do this is:

```
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update, /usr/bin/apt * update, /usr/bin/apt update *
```

The `/usr/bin/apt update` makes the basic command `sudo apt update` passwordless.

The `/usr/bin/apt * update` makes adding an option first like `sudo apt -q update` passwordless.

The `/usr/bin/apt update *` makes adding an option last like `sudo apt update -q` passwordless.

All of these are needed to handle the different ways the command might be called, and the different possible placements of options in the command.

Credit to [Tobias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73397883/11941142) for pointing me in the right direction on this.

Answer (score 2):

I can not test it right now, but according to the link, you could use wildcards:

```
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update *
```

Again, I could no test it - Be careful as always, when you edit the suders file.

Source: https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.7.10/sudoers.man/#Wildcards